# Calculating points of a quadrilateral to emulate fluid in a container (in Swift)

Tags: graphics, geometry, swiftui, linear-algebra

I am trying to create a `FluidView` shape in SwiftUI which acts like a fluid in a container, such that when the device is at a particular angle, so too is the shape / 'fluid'. The shape also has a specific capacity, `percentFilled`, which indicates how much of the parent's view should be filled.

Using these constraints, the invariant for the class is

```swift
lines.area == rect.area * percentFilled
```

where `lines` is the quadrilateral and `rect` is the bounding rectangle. This invariant implies that the 'volume' of the shape remains constant for each `percentFilled` irrespective of the tilt angle.

Here is what I have so far:

```
/// A View made using a specified angle and amount to fill
/// - Invariant: The area of the view is exactly equal to the area of the rectangle of the parent view times `percentFilled`
struct FluidView: Shape {
    var angle: CGFloat = 0.0
    var percentFilled: CGFloat = 0
    
    /// Creates a new FluidView
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - angle: A value in the range `0...1`. A value of `0` indicates the view is horizontal, and an angle of `1` indicates the view is vertical (horizontal if viewed as landscape)
    ///   - percentFilled: the amount of the view bounds to fill represented as a value in the range `0...1`. A value of `x` indicates that `x * 100`% of the parent view is covered by this view
    init(angle: CGFloat = 0, percentFilled: CGFloat = 0) {
        precondition(0...1 ~= angle)
        precondition(0...1 ~= percentFilled)
        
        self.angle = angle
        self.percentFilled = percentFilled
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height * (1 - percentFilled))) // top left
        
        let lines = [
            (0,                                             rect.height                              ), // bottom left
            (rect.width * 1 / (1 + angle - percentFilled),  rect.height                              ), // bottom right
            (rect.width * 1 / (1 + angle - percentFilled),  rect.height * (1 + angle - percentFilled)), // top right
            (0,                                             rect.height * (1 - angle - percentFilled))  // top left
        ].map { x, y in
            // make sure no points exceed the bounds
            CGPoint(x: min(rect.width, x), y: min(rect.height, y))
        }
        
        // invariant
        assert(lines.area == rect.area * percentFilled)
        
        path.addLines(lines)
        return path
    }
}
```

I feel like what I have currently is somewhat close to the goal, however the invariant fails. I believe that my y-coordinates are correct, however I think my calculations for the x-coordinates have to change, but I'm not sure to what they should change.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So it's just like an aircraft level indicator? There's no sloshing or other movement?

Comment: Ideally 'sloshing' would be nice haha, but ya an airline level indicator thingy is really my goal at this stage

Comment: Seems like you could just use a plain rectangle path and then rotate it and offset it along it's rotated y axis... then the tricky part become figuring out the y-offset. You wouldn't need build a new shape from lines for every rotation

Comment: your rectangle will be (could be?) masked by the enclosing view

Comment: @nielsbot ah ok! Any idea what combination of SwiftUI's `rotationEffect`, `offset`, and `frame` would achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
struct FilledShape<S: Shape>: View {
  let shape: S
  @State var angle: Angle = .zero
  @State var percentFull: CGFloat
  
  var gradient: Gradient {
    Gradient(stops: [Gradient.Stop(color: .red, location: 0),
                     Gradient.Stop(color: .red, location: percentFull),
                     Gradient.Stop(color: .blue, location: percentFull),
                     Gradient.Stop(color: .blue, location: 1)])
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    shape.rotation(angle)
      .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
  }
  
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var angle: Angle = .degrees(30)
  var body: some View {
    FilledShape(shape: Rectangle(), angle: angle, percentFull: 0.3).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
  }
}
```

Thing is, percent full is really the percent up along the y axis, not the percent of the area filled. You could use some kind of numeric method with GeometryReader to get the area and read the y-value at the appropriate filled area sum (or if you just use quadrilaterals it's easier). By brute force:

```
extension Shape {
  func area(in box: CGRect) -> Int {
    var area = 0
    for x in 0..<Int(box.width) {
      for y in 0..<Int(box.height) {
        let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        if self.contains(point) {
          area += 1
        }
      }
    }
    return area
  }
}
```

As a different approach, look into SpriteKit and SKPhysicsBody.